# Interpolate Document Properties in Page Widgets

Tags: kentico

Is it possible to have Kentico resolve/interpolate document transformations (CMS.MenuItem) and/or custom page (extends CMS.MenuItem) properties/columns in a widget such as the Head HTML Widget?

Trying to resolve/interpolate something like the following in the `HTML code:` input of the Head HTML Widget on a document page:

`<meta property="og:image" content="https://{%domain%}/foo/bar.jpg" />`

Outputted the following in the  of the page without resolving/interpolating `{%domain%}`:

`<meta property="og:image" content="https://{%domain%}/foo/bar.jpg" />`

Are there restrictions to what can be interpolated within the widget or a widget like it? Or does an additional **setting** need to be activated on the widget created from the "Head HTML Web Part" to allow transformation to execute on page load?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite familiar with the terminology you are using (interpolate within widget?), but I may have an idea what is going on.

By default, Kentico does not resolve any macros within widgets due to security measures so this will not be possible. If you want to resolve macros, you will need to use web part instead.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. So with something like the Head HTML Web Part, to resolve custom page type properties/columns via macros, that could only happen within the web part on the page type's assigned template, not in the individual pages widget?

Comment: Exactly, if you add the 'Head HTML' as a web part, macros will get resolved, but if you add it as widget, macros will not get resolved.